# Why should I use a method instead of using __init__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

In a tutorial that I was watching for Python OOP, they used a method instead of putting it under `__init__`, I want to know what's the difference in creating a method when I can just put it under `__init__`.

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        
    def fullname(self):
        return f'{self.firstname} {self.lastname}'
```

That is the code that they used, and I use the code below which works completely fine.

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.fullname = f'{firstname} {lastname}'
```

Comment: The fullname method in the first example will not work correctly. And in the second example you are passing fullname as an argument for no reason.

Comment: You can make `fullname` a property. Please study python. Lots of good books around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a design decision. Keeping something as a variable will mean retaining it as long as the object exists. Defining it as a function will calculate it's value at runtime.

Since `fullname` is something that can be easily computed at runtime and is derived from already existing variables `firstname` and `lastname` making it somewhat redundant that's why they recommended it to be designed to be a function rather than a variable.

A scenario where you would likely want to store it as a variable is if that value is used very frequently or is computationally expensive to calculate at runtime, you would then have stored it once and re-used it.

But since this is a design decision, it varies case-to-case.

Comment: `It's a design decision` like it!